# Finding residues at a point $a$ where $a$ is a pole.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, complex-numbers, residue-calculus, analyticity

I am faced with the following problem:

> (a) Find $\displaystyle res_{a} \frac{\varphi(z)}{(z-a)^{n}}$ where $\varphi$ is a given function analytic at $a$, $\varphi(a) \neq 0$, and $n$ is a positive integer.
>
> (b) Suppose $a$ is a simple pole of $f$, and let $\displaystyle  res_{a} f = A$. Find $res_{a}(\varphi f)$

I have come up with solutions for both, but I'm not sure if they're right. Here are my answers to **part (a)**:

> (a) Let $\displaystyle f(z) = \frac{\varphi(z)}{(z-a)^{n}}$.  Then, $\displaystyle res_{a}f = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z \to a} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left( f(z) \cdot (z-a)^{n}\right) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z \to a}\frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\left( \frac{\varphi(z)}{(z-a)^{n}} \cdot (z-a)^{n} \right) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \lim_{z \to a} \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}}\varphi(z) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z \to a} \varphi^{(n-1)}(z) = \frac{1}{(n-1)!} \varphi^{(n-1)}(a)$
>
> by the analyticity of $\varphi$ at $a$.

And **part (b)**:

> (b) If $a$ is a simple pole of $f$, then $\displaystyle res_{a} f = \lim_{z \to a} (z-a)f(z) = A$.  Let $\displaystyle g(z) = f(z) \cdot \varphi(z) = \frac{\psi(z)}{(z-a)}\cdot \varphi(z)$. Then, $\displaystyle res_{a}(\varphi f) = res_{a}g = \lim_{z \to a}(z-a)\cdot g = \lim_{z \to a}(z-a)\cdot \frac{\psi(z) \cdot \varphi(z)}{(z-a)} \\ = \lim_{z \to a}(z-a)\frac{\psi(z)}{(z-a)} \cdot \lim_{z \to a} \varphi(z) = A \cdot \lim_{z \to a}\varphi(z) = A \cdot \varphi(a)$.

I especially think that my answer for part (b) is messed up. I know there is a way to calculate the residue of the quotient of two functions, but I don't think I've applied it correctly here.

In any case, please let me know (1) if what I did here is, in fact, correct, and (2) if it is not correct, what it needs in order to make it correct.

Thank you.

Comment: Could anybody *please* let me know if this is right??? I'm very anxious about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both parts look fine. Maybe the second could be formulated somewhat simpler. But let's start with

> **part (a)**: Since $\varphi$ is analytic at $a$, we can find a series representation as *[Taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series)*
>   \begin{align*}
> \varphi(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(z-a)^k\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> res_a\frac{\varphi(z)}{(z-a)^n}
> &=res_a\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{\varphi^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(z-a)^{k-n}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{\varphi^{(n-1)(a)}}{(n-1)!}
> \end{align*}
>
> according to your result of part a.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we select the coefficient of $(z-a)^{-1}$ and take $k=n-1$ accordingly.

> **part (b)**: Since $a$ is a simple pole of $f$ with residuum $A$, we have the representation
>   \begin{align*}
> f(z)=\frac{A}{z-a}+\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}f_k(z-a)^k
> \end{align*}
>   If we consider the multiplication of $f$ with $\varphi$, only the coefficient of $(z-a)^0$
>   \begin{align*}
> \frac{\varphi^{(0)}(a)}{0!}=\varphi(a)
> \end{align*}
>   contributes to the residuum of $f\cdot \varphi$.
>
> We conclude the following rule is valid if a function $f$ with a simple pole at $a$ is multiplied with an analytic function $\varphi$ at $a$
>
> \begin{align*}
> res_a(\varphi f)=\varphi(a)\cdot res_a(f)
> \end{align*}
>   and
>   \begin{align*}
> res_a(\varphi f)=\varphi(a)\cdot A
> \end{align*}
>   follows according to your result of part b.